# Default Navigation Bar Color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, colors

I have some items that change the `UINavigationBar` color when the detail pages are accessed. My issue is getting back to the default `UINavigationBar` color. What color is it? It is not blue or gray for sure.

Also when going "back", where is the best place to put this color change? Unload does not seem to work for this. On the table view controller, Placing the color change at the end of the "`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`" changes it prematurely.

What is the default `UINavigationBar` color?
Where should I place the change when the user is leaving the detail view?

Comment: I am not sure of the color but you would put the code in the viewWillAppear method.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I had tried that one. Perhaps I did, but in the wrong controller. Looks to be working as far as switching back. Still looking for the default navigation RGB color though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can just set the navigation bar color to `nil` and it will revert to its default.

Comment: Thanks to Brian...
The following worked perfectly:

UINavigationBar *bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar]; 
[bar setTintColor:nil];

Answer (score 0):

Color : `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];`

Image :  `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBar_320X44.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`